# forループ内の関数作成をＮＧにする理由

Tags: javascript

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  $(".hoge").each(function() {
    alert("hoge");
  });
}
```

上のように、ループ文の中にfunctionを作成すると、JSHint（JSLintでも同じ）でエラーになります。

> JsHint (W083): Don't make functions within a loop.

なぜループ内に関数を作成してはいけないのでしょうか？

Comment: 検索しやすくするためjshint、jslintタグを追加しました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

詳細な理由は https://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop の
[Why do I get this error?](https://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop#why-do-i-get-this-error-) に書いてあるとおり、
意図したとおりに動かないケースが多いからでしょう。

その動かないケースに該当する質問が、以下のとおり、すでにいくつかなされています。

- [for文でclick時の動作を定義したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1534/for%E6%96%87%E3%81%A7click%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E5%8B%95%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9A%E7%BE%A9%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/1616#1616)
- [どうしてこのsetTimeoutのコードが同じ値ばかり出力していますか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2152/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%93%E3%81%AEsettimeout%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%8C%E5%90%8C%E3%81%98%E5%80%A4%E3%81%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B/2154#2154)

Comment: 「動かないケース」の解決策として提示されているコードにも、forループ内に関数を作成しているものが多くあり、同じ警告が出力されてしまいます。この警告は無視するのがセオリーなのでしょうか。

Comment: ケースバイケースですし、必要に応じて `/*jshint -W083 */` を使えば良いのではないでしょうか。ただバグになりやすいということだけは常に気をつけ、ループ中では関数を返す関数を呼び出すようにするという回避方法も選択肢に入れたほうが良いでしょう。

Comment: @jirolabo JSLintの考え方は、たとえ問題なく動く場合があっても、使う必要はないし最初から避けた方がいいパターンがある、ということです。`for`ループ内の関数作成はそのうちの一つです。JSLintには「このコードは思い通りに動く」というケースを見分ける能力がなく、それがあったとしても、非推薦のパターンを使っている時点ではもう問題ありがちなコードを使っています。

Comment: @jirolabo 「動かないケース」というか意図しない結果の質問に対する回答は、どちらも質問者のセルフ回答でクロージャの説明の流れになっているからですね。（即時関数を使っているので外部関数を使えば期待通りに動くのはわかっていると勝手に解釈して、即時関数を活かす流れで回答していた部分もあります）。束縛するかしないかで結果が大きく変わるので予期せぬ副作用がおこりやすいから危険だよという警告なのでしょう。