# function hoge() と hoge = function() の違いは？

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptでの関数定義には2つあるみたいですが、違いや使い分けがわからないので教えて下さい。

パターン1

```
function hoge(a, b) {
    ...
}
```

パターン2

```
var hoge = function(a, b) {
    ...
}
```

どちらも実行するときは`hoge(a, b);`でよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 11):

両者の本質的な違いは、「式（`Expression`）」か「文（`Statement`)」かだと考えます。

## 関数定義式

パターン2の書き方は*関数定義式*と呼びます。

```
var hoge = function(a, b) {
    ...
}
```

JavaScriptには**巻上げ**という特異な仕様があり、実際には上の記述は以下のように分解されます。

```
// varの宣言はスクリプトまたは関数の行頭で行われる（巻上げ）
var hoge;
// この時点でhogeへアクセスするとundefined
hoge = function(a, b) {
    ...
}
```

また、ここで行われている処理は、匿名関数を変数`hoge`へ代入する処理です。`hoge()`で実行することはできますが、この関数自体が`hoge`という名前は持っていません。

名前を持たせるためには、以下のように宣言する必要があります。

```
var hoge = function fuga(a, b) {
    // この中ではfuga()で再帰処理を書くことができる
    ...
}
// 外側ではhogeはfugaの名前を持つが、呼び出すときはhoge()を用いる
hoge.name // => "fuga"
```

## 関数宣言文

対して、パターン1の書き方は*関数宣言文*と呼ばれます。

```
function hoge(a, b) {
    ...
}
```

**文の巻上げは関数定義そのものに発生する**という特徴があり、その結果、スコープ内であればどこからでも呼び出すことができます。

また、関数宣言文で定義した関数は、必ず名前を持つという特徴があります。

Answer (score 9):

定義されるタイミングの違いについてmozillaに説明がありました。

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function

これは実行されますが:

```
hoisted(); // logs "foo"

function hoisted() {
  console.log("foo");
}
```

これは実行されません:

```
notHoisted(); // TypeError: notHoisted is not a function

var notHoisted = function() {
   console.log("bar");
};
```

また、再帰したい場合などではパターン2の場合でも名前をつける場合があります:

```
var math = {
  'factorial': function factorial(n) {
    if (n <= 1)
      return 1;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

違いはいつ定義されるかという点です。以下の例で`functionOne`は実行時に定義されますが、`functionTwo`は構文解析時に定義されます。

```
<script>
  // Error
  functionOne();

  var functionOne = function() {
  };
</script>

<script>
  // No error
  functionTwo();

  function functionTwo() {
  }
</script>
```

また、`functionTwo`の定義方法では、strictモードの場合、条件節と共に使用することができなくなります。

```
<script>
  "use strict";
  if (test) {
     // Error
     function functionThree() { doSomething(); }
  }
</script>
```

この例でもし`"use strict"`がなければエラーにはならず、`functionThree`は`test`の値に関係なく、定義されることになります。

---

この回答は、英語版にある同様の質問に対する@Gregさんの正解回答を簡易的に訳したものです。

[javascript - var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {} - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 1):

パターン2の使い道は、主にコールバックです。
関数を数値や文字列同様、変数に代入できます、ということは、関数に引数として渡すことも可能です。
非同期処理などで何か行い、完了時に知らせて欲しい場合は、次のようにコールバックすることができます。

```
var hoge = function(a, b) {
   alert( "Completed." );
};

call( hoge );

function call( callback ){
    // 何かいろいろを非同期などで…
    callback( 100 , 200 ); // コールバックする
}
```

Answer (score 1):

実行するときは hoge() でかまいません。どちらも同じ関数として扱うことができます。

違いは、「その行の実行時に関数が定義される」か、それとも「ファイルの読み込み時（パース時）に関数が定義されるか」です。

```
function hoge(a, b) {
    // この関数は Javascript が読み込まれたときに定義される
}

var hoge = function(a, b) {
    // この関数は変数 hoge の文が実行されるときに始めて定義される
}
```

[この質問にあります](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2252/for%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E5%86%85%E3%81%AE%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%82%92%EF%BC%AE%EF%BC%A7%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E7%90%86%E7%94%B1)が、「ループの中で関数を定義するな」というのが、Javascript の書き方で推奨されていたりします。
その理由の一つもこれです。ループの中で、

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var hoge = function(a, b) {
        ...
    }
}
```

と定義してしまうと、実行時に始めて関数が100回定義されてしまうため、パターン１よりも負荷が高くなってしまいがちです。

参考: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 1):

[3100さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2782/3974)のに[同英語版の別解答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/338053/4366452)から付け足すと、パターン1はhogeという名の関数を宣言してますが、パターン2では無名関数を宣言し、それを変数hogeに入れていることになります。これが実用上で起こせる違いとしては、

```
var hoge = function(){};
```

とするとスコープはローカルですが、

```
hoge = function(){};
```

とすることでグローバルに定義できます。
変数を使うことでeval()内で使ってもスコープが何処だかはっきりするので、デバッグが楽であり、ブラウザ間での互換性を保つことが出来ます（eval内で関数宣言するとブラウザごとに宣言される位置が違うらしい…）。

またパターン2は無名関数なので、Function.name(**非標準、IEはサポートしてません**)が以下のように空文字になります。

```
function hoge1(){};
var hoge2 = function(){};
console.log(hoge1.name);//"hoge1"
console.log(hoge2.name);//""
```

Answer (score 1):

挙動の違いは少なくて実質交換可能でも、意味としての違いがあります。
例えばオブジェクトにいろいろ入れて返すような場合、つまり関数を値として生成したい場合はパターン2で書かれると思います。
一方、その関数を関数内で使いたい場合、つまり関数を関数として設置したい場合はパターン１で書かれると思います。
まあ挙動の差があまりないので、気分で変えたり、なるべくどちらかに統一しているような人も多いかもしれません。

因みに挙動の差としては巻き上げの他に、パターン１ではブロックスコープになるということがあります。

```
(function () {
  "use strict"
  var fn = function () { return 1 }
  {
    function fn() { return 2 }
    console.log( fn() )  // 2
  }
  console.log( fn() )  // 1
})()
```

Comment: ES5にはブロックスコープはないのでは？ 
上記の記述は、先に定義された`function fn()`が、変数`fn`に上書きされているだけのように見えます。 
関数がスコープを持つという点ではパターン1も2も変わらないと思います。擬似ブロックスコープを作るために、無名の即時関数が利用されることはよくありますが。

Comment: 例があまり良くなかったので修正しました。この挙動はES6のもので既にChromeなどでサポートされています。

Comment: なるほど、ES6では未定義だったブロック内での文での関数宣言が`let`相当になる機能のことですね。ここでの「JavaScript」は前提としてメインストリームであるES5を指しているものと考えておりました、失礼しました。